# Heroku Deployment Error: npm ERR! Host key verification failed. NextJS/ExpressJS App

Tags: express, heroku, next.js

I am attempting to deploy my Next.js/Express,js backend app to Heroku via GitHub, however, I keep receiving the following error:

If anyone can please help me resolve this issue, that would be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

[image]

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.5...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.14
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! Error while executing:
       npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/securedeveloper/js-xlsx.git
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
       npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
       npm ERR! and the repository exists.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ScCS4/_logs/2021-08-22T17_21_36_340Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: Host key verification failed, Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531764/heroku-host-key-verification-failed-could-not-read-from-remote-repository)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a good solution, but after removing package-lock.json and pushing again the error disappeared

Comment: I don't know why this works, but you made my day!